# How to make the background of a expander or grid control a glass like look?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Just like the question how can make it look glassy? I just want one solid glass look though. What I have below is a linear gradient, I want a solid blurry glassy look but still be able to see all my content in front of it.

```
     <Grid.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush Opacity="10" ColorInterpolationMode="ScRgbLinearInterpolation" EndPoint="1,10">

                        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="2"/>

                        <GradientStop Color="Ivory" Offset="0"/>

                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Grid.Background>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need the Gradient to accomplish the glassy effect unless you maybe want to stack a shape or a path on top like half way up, white, with a reduced opacity. Maybe an example of whats meant by a "solid" and "blurry" glassy look would help others visualize? Because those sound pretty opposite? Or you could just stick with LinearGradient's

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TestBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFF9FBFC" Offset="0.081"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFCFE0FD" Offset="0.474"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFB4C5FF" Offset="0.481"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFD0DFFD" Offset="0.906"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFD3E6FC" Offset="0.202"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFB4CBFF" Offset="0.734"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
```